# D3.js zooming with axis

Tags: d3.js, svg, slider, zooming, pan

I have a project where I need to zoom on 3 axes independently.  I'm using scroll bars to accomplish this, but the axes aren't redrawing when the zoom happens.

Additionally, the clip path doesn't seem to be working as expected.

Eventually I want to add panning functionality to the chart as well, but I'm not sure where to start for this.

http://jsfiddle.net/yo4mwLpj/

Thanks in advance for the help.

```
// cases vs deaths of a disease over time
var data = [
{"year": "1960", "cases":"887",   "deaths": "199"},
{"year": "1965", "cases":"218",   "deaths": "55"},
{"year": "1993", "cases":"37046", "deaths": "931"},
{"year": "1994", "cases":"38735", "deaths": "118"},
{"year": "1995", "cases":"19903", "deaths": "624"},
{"year": "1997", "cases":"4170",  "deaths": "125"},
{"year": "1998", "cases":"10000", "deaths": "0"}
];
data.forEach(function (d) {
   d.year   = d3.time.format("%Y").parse(d.year.toString());
   d.cases  = +d.cases;
   d.deaths = +d.deaths;
});

var margin = { top: 30, right: 40, bottom: 30, left: 50 },
   width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
   height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var xScale = d3.time.scale()
   .domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return d.year; }))
   .range([0, width]);

var yScaleLeft = d3.scale.linear()
   .domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.cases; })])
   .range([height, 0]);

var yScaleRight = d3.scale.linear()
   .domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.deaths; })])
   .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
   .scale(xScale)
   .orient("bottom").ticks(5);

var yAxisLeft = d3.svg.axis()
   .scale(yScaleLeft)
   .orient("left").ticks(5);

var yAxisRight = d3.svg.axis()
   .scale(yScaleRight)
   .orient("right").ticks(5);

var lineCases = d3.svg.line()
   .x(function (d) { return xScale(d.year); })
   .y(function (d) { return yScaleLeft(d.cases); });

var lineDeaths = d3.svg.line()
   .x(function (d) { return xScale(d.year); })
   .y(function (d) { return yScaleRight(d.deaths); });

var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
   .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
   .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
   .append("g")
   .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("g")
   .attr("class", "x axis")
   .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
   .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
   .attr("class", "y axis yleft")
   .call(yAxisLeft);

svg.append("g")
   .attr("class", "y axis yright")
   .call(yAxisRight)
   .attr('transform', 'translate(' + width + ',0)');

svg.append("path")
   .datum(data)
   .attr("class", "line lineLeft")
   .style("stroke", "red")
   .attr("d", lineCases(data))
   .attr("clip", "url(#clip)");

svg.append("path")
   .datum(data)
   .attr("class", "line lineRight")
   .attr("d", lineDeaths(data))
   .attr("clip", "url(#clip)");

svg.append("clipPath")
   .attr("id", "clip")
   .append("rect")
   .attr("width", width)
   .attr("height", height);

$("#slider-x").slider({
   orientation: "horizontal",
   range: "min",
   min: 1000,
   max: 10000, // make max be (maxDate-minDate).Days*1000, so you can zoom to one day
   value: 1000,
   slide: function( event, ui ) {
      zoomXWithSlider(ui.value/1000);
   }
});

$( "#slider-y-left" ).slider({
   orientation: "vertical",
   range: "min",
   min: 1000,
   max: 10000,
   value: 1000,
   slide: function( event, ui ) {
      zoomLeftWithSlider(ui.value/1000);
   }
});

$("#slider-y-right").slider({
   orientation: "vertical",
   range: "min",
   min: 1000,
   max: 10000,
   value: 1000,
   slide: function( event, ui ) {
      zoomRightWithSlider(ui.value/1000);
   }
});

function zoomXWithSlider(scale) {
   // Note: works only on the <g> element and not on the <svg> element
     // which is a common mistake
   svg.selectAll("path.line").attr("transform", "scale("+scale+", 1)");
   svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
}

function zoomLeftWithSlider(scale) {
   svg.select("path.line.lineLeft").attr("transform", "scale(1, "+scale+")");
   svg.select(".y.axis.yleft").call(yAxisLeft);
}

function zoomRightWithSlider(scale) {
   svg.select("path.line.lineRight").attr("transform", "scale(1, "+scale+")");
   svg.select(".y.axis.yright").call(yAxisRight);
}
```

Comment: There are many issues. More than I'm able to get into now to write a full answer. To begin with, when you react to the slider changes and redraw the axes,  you must also modify the scale on which the axes are based, otherwise they just redraw the same thing (as you're seeing). For example, on the X, you might do something like `xScale.range([0, width*scale])` prior to redrawing the axis. You might want to refactor things such that when the slider value changes, you capture just the new scale value and then redraw all or most of the chart, to avoid code repetition.

Comment: Once you get into panning, you'll need to also modify the first element (the `0`, above) of the affected range, which is further reason to refactor things.

Comment: There are multiple reasons clipPath is not working. First, a `clipPath` should be a child of a `<defs>` section. And instead of `clip` attribute, you need to specify `clip-path` (as in `.attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");`). But there's still an issue that by scaling the `<path>` when the slider is dragged, the clipPath is implicitly scaled as well, which means it doesn't continue to crop based on the constant chart width. To see what I mean, I purposely set the mask's width to `width/2`, to crop half the chart. See how it grows when you slide the x slider: http://jsfiddle.net/tvvcbrob/

Comment: I've gotten the zooming to work by updating the scale domains then redrawing the appropriate elements.  Now I need to implement panning and the clip path.  http://jsfiddle.net/0t19wq20/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/8oo3ocfs/

```
    var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom() //zoomYAxis
   .x(xScale)
   .y(yScaleLeft)
   .on("zoom", function(){
      // don't let double-click or scroll wheel do anything
      if (d3.event.sourceEvent == null || d3.event.sourceEvent.type == "wheel"){
         zoom.scale(previousScale);
         zoom.translate(previousTranslate);
         zoomRight.scale(previousScale);
         zoomRight.translate(previousTranslate);
         return;
      }

      // set previous scale for future use
      previousScale = zoom.scale();
      previousTranslate = zoom.translate();

      //zoom.translate(panLimit());
      //zoomRight.translate(zoom.translate());

      // update the right side scale
      zoomRight.scale(previousScale);
      zoomRight.translate(previousTranslate);

      // redraw lines
      svg.select("path.line.lineLeft").attr("d", lineCases(data));
      svg.select("path.line.lineRight").attr("d", lineDeaths(data));

      // redraw axes
      svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
      svg.select(".y.axis.yleft").call(yAxisLeft);
      svg.select(".y.axis.yright").call(yAxisRight);
   });
```

I eventually got this working.  I don't need the clip-path to work in the jsfiddle because it works in our actual project.  Additionally, I didn't end up limiting the pan functionality because it got very complex with the math.  So I just put a reset button on it.